# Google Cloud storage upload method is returning signed URL. Django python

Tags: python-3.x, django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

This is my upload image method

```
from storages.backends.gcloud import GoogleCloudStorage

storage = GoogleCloudStorage()


def upload_image(file, dir_name, filename):
    try:
        target_path = '/static/images/' + dir_name + '/' + filename
        path = storage.save(target_path, file)
        return storage.url(path)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

This is my settings in the django settings.py

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
GS_BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket name'
GS_PROJECT_ID = "project id"

GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'google_cloud_credientials.json')
)
```

I have used this tutorial for reference **https://medium.com/@mohammedabuiriban/how-to-use-google-cloud-storage-with-django-application-ff698f5a740f**

This is returning me the signed URL for the file which I have uploaded and expired after some time, but I want to have a public URL that will be available for any time.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to have a public URL that will be available for any time.

Your only option for a URL that does not expire is to make the object public and use a Google Cloud Storage endpoint in this format:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME
```

Refer to this document:

[Google Cloud Storage: Make data public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public)